# Electron: How to refocus/restore a minimised DevTools window

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I've created a global shortcut where `Ctrl+Shift+I` opens a detached DevTools window. However, when the DevTools window is minimised, pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I` does not do anything.

I want to be able to restore/unminimise the minimised DevTools window by using the `Ctrl+Shift+I` shortcut. The `.focus` method usually works for things like this but doesn't in this case. I've tried using 'undocked' mode for the window too.

The code I have to implement the current behaviour is this:

```
if (focussedWindow.webContents.isDevToolsOpened()) {
      if (focussedWindow.webContents.devToolsWebContents !== null) {                            
              focussedWindow.webContents.devToolsWebContents.focus();
       }
}
```

I should also add that the DevTools window does refocus if it is behind other windows, just not when minimised.

I'm using Electron 9.3.0 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Pressing it twice should do it right? The first time it closes, the second time it opens. I'm probably missing something.

Comment: What do you mean by minimised? Do you mean closed? Do you know [`webContents.toggleDevTools()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentstoggledevtools)?

Comment: @evolutionbox - If I were using mouse clicks, this would work, but I want to use the keyboard shortcuts to refocus - I should have mentioned that I'm using 'detach' mode (@snwflk) so devtools is opened in a separate window (will edit description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Situation

On Linux, [`BrowserWindow.webContents.devToolsWebContents.focus()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsfocus)  restores the minimized detached DevTools window – as desired.

On Windows, this does not work (tested with Electron 9.3.0 and 10.1.1 on Win 7). The minimized detached DevTools window stays minimized.

#### Workaround

After trying *many* workarounds that all did not work on Windows, I found the following trick: make a new BrowserWindow for the DevTools to occupy. With this reference, you can now simply call [`BrowserWindow.restore()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winrestore).

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow, newDevToolsWindow;

app.on("ready", function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true
    }));

    console.log("create new window for devtools")
    newDevToolsWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    mainWindow.webContents.setDevToolsWebContents(newDevToolsWindow.webContents);
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({mode: "detach"});

    // Simulate OP's keypress
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log("restore the new window")
        newDevToolsWindow.restore();
    }, 4000);

});
```

Notes:

- The workaround was tested with Electron 9.3.0 and 10.1.1 on Win 7.
- You may need to adapt the BrowserWindow a little, if you want to replicate the standard DevTools window behavior in detach mode.
- Also note that `isDevToolsOpened` will return `false`, so you need to adapt your checks as well.

Comment: Thanks - however this didn't seem to work. ```webContents.isDevToolsOpened()``` returns true when devtools window is minimised. I did try removing the check anyway but no luck.

Comment: That's intriguing. I assume you're on Windows? Could you add the OS and Electron version into your question?

Comment: Electron version: 9.3.0
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @PaperBoy I found a workaround for Windows and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this snwflk :)  ```.setDevToolsWebContents```. The window now restores from minimised and should be workable with a few tweaks.